# Why do I get a 32-bit error when I use 64-bit PC?

Tags: python, 64-bit, numba

I want to use the `umap-learn` package.
As in the [documentation](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap) guide, I try to run the simplest example

```
import umap.umap_ as umap # in the documentation the line is import umap
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
embedding = umap.UMAP().fit_transform(digits.data)
```

I get the error

```
The 'parallel' target is not currently supported on 32 bit hardware.
During: lowering "id=7[LoopNest(index_variable = parfor_index.249, range = (0, $38binary_subscr.17, 1))]{46: <ir.Block at path\to\my\env\...\python_env\lib\site-packages\umap\utils.py (32)>}Var(parfor_index.249, utils.py:32)" at path\to\my\env\...\python_env\lib\site-packages\umap\utils.py (32)
```

I use 64-bit, - the code `platform.machine().endswith('64')` return `True`.

The python is version 3.8.

How can I use `umap` properly?

Thanks

Comment: Is the Python interpreter 32-bit or 64-bit? In both cases, `platform.machine()` returns `"AMD64"` on my machine. Maybe your Python interpreter is 32-bit?

Comment: You right. I checked with method 2 in this https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-check-if-python-is-32-or-64-bit-windows/#:~:text=Press%20Enter%20key%20to%20open,%2Dbit%20version%20(%20MSC%20v. link and this's 32-bit.